# Is there a way to auto approve bamboo remote agent without manually approving it on the bamboo server?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, bamboo

Currently, I am starting a container with bamboo remote agent on it and every time I need to manually approve the bamboo agent on the bamboo server. The idea is to automate the whole process starting with running a container which launches a bamboo remote agent and performs the build and then to kill the container. Since bamboo server expects manual approval, this is posing as a challenge. So I am looking for a way to auto approve the agent to register it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an option to automatically auto-approve agents. Agent approval requirement is an security feature so auto approving any remote agent wouldn't be a security feature anyhow.

That being said, there's an option to **disable agent authentication** which will effectively mean that any *new agent is approved right away* -> actually what you're asking for.

You can disable agent authentication by visiting Bamboo administration [pages](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/agent-authentication-289277196.html)

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for.